# PyGame Moving Animation and issue with background

Tags: pygame

here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
FPS=30

clock=pygame.time.Clock()
white=(255,255,255) #background
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((480,320)) #screen size
pygame.display.set_caption("Zombie Game!")
mainsheet=pygame.image.load("C:\Python34\MyMan.png") #load image
sheet_size=mainsheet.get_size() #get size of img

steps_right=8 #first 8 pictures is moving to the right
jump=16 #next 8 (actually 5) is jumping
steps_left=24 #next 8 is moving to the left 
cell_width=int(sheet_size[0]/8) #width of the one animation
cell_height=int(sheet_size[1]/4) #height of the one animation

cell_list=[]
for y in range(0,sheet_size[1],int(cell_height)): #looping through image 
    for x in range(0,sheet_size[0],int(cell_width)):

        surface=pygame.Surface((cell_width,cell_height))
        surface.blit(mainsheet,(0,0),(x,y,cell_width,cell_height))

        cell_list.append(surface) #adding images to list


cell_position=0

running=True

pygame.key.set_repeat(50, 50) #if they hold the key
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:            
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT: #if to the right..
                if cell_position <steps_right-1:
                    cell_position+=1
                else:
                    cell_position=0
            if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                if cell_position<steps_left-1 and cell_position>jump:
                    cell_position+=1
                else:
                    cell_position=jump+1
            if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
                if cell_position<12 and cell_position>7:
                    cell_position+=1
                else:
                    cell_position=8
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(cell_list[cell_position],(100,10))
    clock.tick(FPS)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I know that maybe it isn't the best way to do it but it's my first try. But there are 2 problems(at least): 1)"Character" is moving(animated) but of course he doesn't move and I dont have any idea how to do that ,if it was only simple rectangle then I would,but this is a little bit complicated ..and 2) when I try to change the background to white instead of black,my character is in the small black square but background is white..thanks for help!!!! :-))

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

"C:\Python34\MyMan.png": please start this with r"" or use double slashes. Otherwise, if you put this in a directory starting with n or something, things will break.

Background color is caused (presumably) by using a non-transparent image. png supports transparency. I think there might be a flag to send to Pygame to mark it as transparent, but I don't remember what it is.

For movement, look at the line screen.blit(cell_list[cell_position],(100,10)). That's an xy coordinate pair; change those from constants to variables, and change them in the event loop.